# Cannot resolve symbol card,dependency error in android studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I tried to cardslib to my project. I added dependency as per the document.But still i got error as "Cannot resolve symbol card","Cannot resolve symbol cardHeader".

**MainActivity:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        //Create a Card
        Card card = new Card(getContext());

        //Create a CardHeader
        CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getContext());
        ....
        //Add Header to card
        card.addCardHeader(header);

        cards.add(card);

        CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(),cards);

        CardListView listView = (CardListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myList);
        if (listView!=null){
            listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
        }
    }
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myList"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:0.6.0'
}
```

Comment: I think there is button on tool bar to force Android Studio to re-read dependencies from gradle build file

Comment: Yes, the button is to the left of the avd button.

Comment: I came upon this question after searching because I've had similar problems with this and I'm using intelij. I tried copying the source files to a libraries folder in my project and also the maven dependency to download it from the repo and I couldn't get either to work. Please let me know if you were able to get this library working and the steps you took. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Invalidate the cache of Android Studio by going to `File -> Invalidate Caches`. This Will probably solve the issue.